# Inserting Resultset into Arraylist and displaying them

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have difficult storing multiple result sets into an ArrayList. Also I need to display them in a JTextArea. But the problem is, I can't get it to display anything.

```
public static ArrayList<Wall> getWallPosts(int postId){

    ArrayList<Wall> postList = new ArrayList<Wall>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    DBController db = new DBController();

    db.setUp("myDatabase");
    String dbQuery = "SELECT Id FROM Wall WHERE ID ="+postId; 

    rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);

    try{
       while (rs.next()){
            int wallId = rs.getInt("Id");
            String wallPoster = rs.getString("Poster");
            String wallPost = rs.getString("Post");
            String wallDate = rs.getString("Tdate");
            Wall w1 = new Wall(wallPoster, wallPost , wallDate);
            postList.add(w1);   
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }


    db.terminate();
    return postList;

}
    //The method for displaying the result sets
        public void retrieveCategoryQuestionList() {
    //get the list and store in array
    ArrayList<Wall> aList = Wall.getWallPosts(id);
    for(id = 1; id<aList.size();id++)
        jTextAreaWall.append(w2.getPost());
}
```

The fields in the database is Id, Poster, Post, Tdate

Comment: For future reference, bear in mind that your question doesn't exactly say *what* is wrong - you just say "I can't get it to display anything", and post a chunk of code.  (This is particularly bad because in this situation you must have been getting an exception, so listing that and the stacktrace would have helped a lot).  [Further reading](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Comment: Ok, the problem is when I run the method below, it just runs DB Query: SELECT * FROM Wall WHERE ID =0. I have changed the codes according to what they said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your SQL query:

```
"SELECT Id FROM Wall WHERE ID ="+postId
```

You're selecting only the `Id` from the table while you expect `Id`, `Poster`, `Post` and `Tdate` to be present as per your `ResultSet#getString()` calls.

```
String wallPoster = rs.getString("Poster");
String wallPost = rs.getString("Post");
String wallDate = rs.getString("Tdate");
Wall w1 = new Wall(wallPoster, wallPost , wallDate);
```

You need to specify those columns in your SQL query as well:

```
"SELECT Id, Poster, Post, Tdate FROM Wall WHERE Id="+ postId
```

#### See also:

- [SQL tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/)

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, I'd suggest to [familarize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) yourself with `PreparedStatement` since that's the one which prevents SQL injection attacks.

---

**Update**: as per the comment on your own question, if your intent is to display ALL rows, then you should just not add a restrictive `WHERE` clause, even not with a `Id=0`, that would only search for records matching `Id=0`. Just omit the `WHERE`.

```
"SELECT Id, Poster, Post, Tdate FROM Wall"
```

Once again, I recommend to get yourself through a basic SQL tutorial. This issue has in essence not much to do with Java/JDBC. Aside from a few serious design issues, it should just work.

Comment: Also, the exception "handling" via `e.printStackTrace();` is really bad and will obscure any problems such as this on.  DB-accessing methods should always have an unambiguous way of signalling failure (ideally propagating *some* exception unless used in a very limited scope)!

Comment: @Andrzej: agreed. And then I'm not talking about the not closing of resources in `finally`. To the OP: you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful then to get new insights.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other errors that could be, it looks ok to me, just that

String dbQuery = "SELECT Id FROM Wall WHERE ID ="+postId;

Should be:

```
String dbQuery = "SELECT Id FROM Wall WHERE ID ='"+postId+"'";
```